# MS Chart library

Tags: c#, .net, charts, mschart

I have rather little experience with the MS Chart library and would need some help working with dates on the X Axis of the chart... basically I need to customize the X Axis to show both date (as an interval between 2 major markers lets say) and also hours (which should be based on business hours - day should start at 9:00 and end at 17:00 lets say).
I already wrote a custom chart which draws what I need, but lacks lost of the cool features of the MS chart library - zooming, printing etc...)

What I need to achieve can be seen in this image:

[image: a]
<sub>(source: [croitoriu.com](http://croitoriu.com/datetime_chart.jpg))</sub>

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to get this and any idea how?
The application with the chart samples didn't help much in this regard...

Thank you!

Andrei

Comment: you can add striplines between your interval.

Comment: @ManishSharma not sure I follow... could you give some more details or provide a link to some sort of example or api reference? Thanks!